# Centering a TextView while keeping it to the left of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

**Requirement**

I've got a button and a textview, and I want the textview to be centered in the parent view, while the button is on the right side in the parent view.

**Approach**

So I took a RelativeLayout, make the textview layout_centerHorizontal="true", and the button layout_alignParentRight="true".

**Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_header_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
       <!--  Doesnt work -->
       <!--  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"  -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem**

So when the text is too long, it gets written on top of the button.

I tried doing layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button" on the textview, but now TextView is no longer centered.

Comment: add `android:ellipsize="end"` in Textview tag.

Comment: @GiruBhai It didn't work. Did it work for you?? Also, what does android:ellipsize do??

Comment: what do you want to happen when the text is too long? `ellipsize="end"` shortens the text and adds three dots at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_header_TV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />


</TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems to be the most appropriate answer. But it won't work if button text is too long. Also the TextView won't expand a certain limit if the button text is too short.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <!--  Doesnt work -->
   <!--  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"  -->
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
    android:text="Button" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_header_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

try this

Comment: It didn't work. Did it work for you?? I couldn't use layout_alignBottom="@+id/right_button" because I'm already using this tag with some other view. Will that make a difference??

Comment: Also, what does android:layout_alignBaseline do??

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_header_TV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is a test message, This is a test message This is a test message " />
<!-- Doesnt work -->
<!-- android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button" -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Did it work for you?? I couldn't use layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1" because I'm already using this tag with some other view. Will that make a difference??

Comment: Also, what does android:layout_alignBaseline do??

Comment: Now the text is not center aligned if its length is small.

Comment: its center aligned for me

make sure
 android:layout_width="match_parent"

for textview

Answer (score 0):

Please change to
`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_header_TV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/right_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/right_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

`

Comment: Why should I use android:layout_below when I want the button to be on the right?? My view is horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work . I want the text to be in center as per the parent view(center horizontal of the RelativeLayout).

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <!--  Doesnt work -->
   <!--  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"  -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Add your demo text here for small and large"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"/>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will not guarantee that my button is right aligned(when text is too small). This view will also vary for different screen sizes & densities. Also I cannot choose width in pixels, due to same screen sizes & densities reason.

Comment: 1)For Small Text you can test that button is still on its position.2)For Different Screen size you can create different layout(I hope you know how to do this)3)about screen sizes and desnsity you can use what is best suited according to your requirement

Comment: Giving fixed width in dp to my TextView & then aligning my button as per that TextView doesn't seem to be a good idea. Also my manager will never approve of this code during review.

Comment: Nope. Look carefully at your Graphical Layout. I want it in horizontal center of the parent. As of now its in center of the space left apart from the button. Just look carefully.

Comment: android:gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: As per your mention statement "So when the text is too long, it gets written on top of the button." i think its working what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_header_TV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

check this out. a very simple solution for you

Comment: What!! It absolutely doesn't work. I want the text to be in center as per the parent view(center horizontal of the RelativeLayout).